# create variable from string given in array

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to create variable from String inside the array with the name of the String?

something like this:

```
            const array = ["type","name","hours","photos","place","price"];

            array.forEach(item =>{
                let item = document.crea..... 
                 //but it should work like let array[index] = docu.......
            })
```

The reason for this is that I wanted to make this code look a bit nicer and its obvious, that there are quite a lot things repeating.

```
            const type = document.createElement("td");
            const name = document.createElement("td");
            const hours = document.createElement("td");
            const photos = document.createElement("td");
            const place = document.createElement("td");
            const price = document.createElement("td");

            type.innerHTML = element.type;
            name.innerHTML = element.name;
            hours.innerHTML = element.hours;
            photos.innerHTML = element.photos;
            place.innerHTML = element.place;
            price.innerHTML = element.price;

            tr.appendChild(type);
            tr.appendChild(name);
            tr.appendChild(hours);
            tr.appendChild(photos);
            tr.appendChild(place);
            tr.appendChild(price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `var` or `let`  instead `const`,works for me always.
And remember foreach is a kind of loop means

```
var mytd = document.createElement("td");mytd.innerHTML = element.{item};tr.appendChild(mytd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question about variable names, but this should be the code you need to get your result.

```
array.forEach(item => {
    const elem = tr.appendChild(document.createElement("td"));
    elem.innerHTML = item;
})
```

You don't really need to use your array to generate the variable name as the forEach handles each item in the array separately.

Comment: This article may give some clarity on why it's okay to use **const** in a forEach. 
[Why ‘const’ works in a ‘for…in’ loop but not in a normal ‘for’ loop](https://medium.com/@mautayro/es6-variable-declaration-for-loops-why-const-works-in-a-for-in-loop-but-not-in-a-normal-a200cc5467c2)